# How to construct the Riemann surface for $\sqrt[4]{1-z^4}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

> I want to construct the Riemann surface for the function:
> $w=\sqrt[4]{1-z^4}.$

My attempt:

I can see that the branch points must be at 4 roots of unity. I cut two slits joining $1$ and $-1$ and another slit joining the remaining two points (along the imaginary axis while passing through infinity). It looks like if I move around small contour covering the slit joining 1 and -1, the function $\sqrt[4]{1-z^4}$ changes to negative of itself. So this means I am not in the same sheet.

Note that, by Riemann-Hurwitz, the Riemann surface should be the genus 3 surface. However I want to get the space explicitly by branch cuts and gluing. How do I get the Riemann surface of the function?

Reference request: Most of the websites and literature seems to be filled with Riemann surfaces of square roots of polynomials or higher roots of linear polynomials. If there are any references for constructing Riemann surface of higher roots of higher degree polynomials, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: "It looks like if I move around small contour covering the slit joining $1$ and $-1$, the function $\sqrt{1-z^4}$ changes to negative of itself." - I'm guessing that even though you claimed to have cut the plane from $1$ to $-1$, and from $i$ to $\infty$ and $\infty$ to $-i$, when you calculated $\sqrt{1-z^4}$ on your contour, you used a method that put the branch cuts elsewhere. In any case, we need to see how you arrived at this conclusion to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Is treating it as $w^4+z^4=1$ acceptable for the construction?

Comment: @onriv: Yeah sure. The question is motivated by a problem in the first chapter of  Fomenko and Fuchs (Homotopical topology): Show that the real surface $\{[x_0;x_1;x_2] \in \mathbb{C}P^2 | x_0^n + x_1 ^n + x_2^n = 0\}$ is an orientable surface of genus $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$. I wanted to solve the problem for $n=4$ by explicitly computing the Riemann surface (by branch cuts and then gluing sheets). The equation $w^4 + z^4 =1$ is the equation of the curve in an affine chart.

Comment: How about cut the complex plane from $\infty$ to $-1$ and $1$ to $\infty$, and $\infty$ to $-i$ and $i$ to $\infty$? In such a way the domain is simply connected, and we get 4 sheets. But I cannot see how the gluing procedure works and how to imagine it has 3 holes intuitively too

Comment: Hi. Since this Riemann surface has genus 3, do you think rather than cutting the complex planes and gluing them, is it possible to construct it as the direct sum of two tori?